# .NET Core pod can't connect to SQL Server pod in Kubernetes

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, kubernetes, .net-core

I have a .NET Core pod that needs to access to SQL Server pod in Kubernetes(docker-desktop).
Using port forwarding I can connect to that SQL Server from SQL Server Management Studio. But when I trying to connect from .NET Core pod then it says

> The server was not found or was not accessible

Here is the error from log

```
[04:28:38 Error] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection
An error occurred using the connection to database 'MyTestDatabase' on server 'tcp:sqlserver-service,1433'.

[04:28:38 Error] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

My Connection String in Container

```
Server=tcp:sqlserver-service,1433;User ID=sa;Password=myPass12;Initial Catalog=MyTestDatabase;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Connection Timeout=30;
```

SQL Server deployment yml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: sqldata
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/sqldata"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dbclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sqlserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sqlserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sqlserver
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: sqldata-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: dbclaim
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      initContainers:
       - name: volume-permissions
         image: busybox
         command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 10001:0 /var/opt/mssql"]
         volumeMounts:
         - mountPath: "/var/opt/mssql"
           name: sqldata-storage
      containers:
        - name: sqlserver1
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
          env:
            - name: MSSQL_PID
              value: "Developer"
            - name: SA_PASSWORD
              value: "myPass12"
            - name: ACCEPT_EULA
              value: "Y"
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/var/opt/mssql/data"
            name: sqldata-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sqlserver-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: sqlserver
    port: 1433
    targetPort: 1433
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: sqlserver
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Connect from SQL Server Management Studio

[image]

Surely I am missed something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the database exists in ms sql that you are trying to connect with the core service?

Comment: The connection string should match the login window of SSMS.  The login windows shows the server name/instance.  Also will indicate with Window Credential or SQL Credential.  If Window Credential than the connection string should not have Username/Password.  Instead in connection string use Integrated Security = true.

Comment: @HarshManvar yes database is existed.

Comment: @jdweng SQL Credential is enabled and I can login using SA account from SSMS

Comment: Can you try with the Linux image make sure you change the PVC or PV as it will be storing the configuration with change the container configuration wont ger rewrite so create the new PVC or PV for testing of the Linux.

Comment: If you are running c# from same machine as running SSMS then everything should work as long as the Server/Instance is same in c# and SSMS.  I would make the Server in the connection string match exactly what is in the login window.  No need for TCP garbage.

Comment: @jdweng dot core app and sql server run in kubernetes pod and SSMS run in Host machine.

Comment: Still the Server/Instance has to be the same.  Do you know if you have a route from the kubernetes to the server?  Did you try Ping to verify a route?

Comment: @jdweng Basically I use kubernetes service to communicate between pods.

Answer (score 2):

It`s my bad. Actually selector of service was wrong.

```
 selector:
    name: sqlserver
```

It should be

```
 selector:
    app: sqlserver
```

Thank you all

Comment: it's should be the right answer, so i add, the type of the network service must be ClusterIP not a LoadBlancer